# How can I use a catch all route using `path` or `re_path` so that Django passes all unmatched requests to my index view?

Tags: django, django-urls

My url patterns look like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('api.urls')),

    re_path('.*', IndexView.as_view()),
]
```

This works but it matches *all* URLs, including those prefixed with `admin` and `api`. I want those URLs to still match, and for any unmatched URLs to render `IndexView`.

Before 2.0 I used this regex for this purpose. I tried using it in `re_path` but that didn't work, which is what led me to trying the above.

```
url(r'^(?P<path>.*)/$', HtmlView.as_view())
```

Use case is a SPA where I handle 404s client side.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If `url(r'^(?P<path>.*)/$', HtmlView.as_view())` worked in earlier versions of Django, then it should work in Django 2.0 as well. You can replace `url` with `re_path`, but that shouldn't change the behaviour.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So as I said in the question description, trying the regex I was using before Django 2.0 in re_path did not work. It would basically match for all requests *except* `/` (i.e., index path). I fixed this by using both that regex and a second path matching `/` specifically. Here's the code:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^(?P<path>.*)/$', IndexView.as_view()),
    path('', IndexView.as_view()),
]
```

With these changes my other routes would match and these two routes would account for all other urls.

Answer (score 14):

You can use two entries (one for '/', another one for anything else), but using `path` for both of them, which should be (slightly) more efficient:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', IndexView.as_view(), {'resource': ''}),
    path('<path:resource>', IndexView.as_view())
]
```

In this case, I'm using `<path:resource>` because `path` catches all resource names, inluding that with `/` in them. But it does not capture the main index resource, `/`. That's why the first entry. The dictionary as last argument for it is because we need to provide a `resource` parameter if we want to use the same view than in the second entry.

That view, of course, should have 'resource' as a paremeter:

```
def as_view(request, resource):
   ...
```

Comment: Small remark: in the first urlpattern, `resource` should be `'resource'`.

Comment: Great answer. I used in the view the kwarg reource=None, but I guess that's more a personal preference.

Answer (score 7):

One Idea to go about this is let the django catch 404.

## url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import handler404

handler404 = 'app_name.views.bad_request'
```

and in your views.py

## views.py

```
def bad_request(request):
    return redirect(reverse('home'))
```

You can always do some regex thingy to catch unmatched urls. but hey this gets the job done. :)

Comment: You can even set `handler404 = IndexView.as_view()`, and avoid having to redirect.